# MySQL ordering join results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I don't understand why this query isn't working as expected. I have a horse table and file table. The file table has columns "fk_object" and "fk_id" so I can get records like fk_object="horse_photo" and fk_id=725. The file table also has is_default and position columns so I can grab the file (photo) that should be its profile picture. However, I'm not getting the default photo or even first position file. Can someone explain to me why this query doesn't work as expected and what the proper solution would be? Thanks!

```
SELECT `horse`.`id`,
       `horse`.`name`,
       `file`.`id` AS `fid`,
       `file`.`is_default`,
       `file`.`position`
FROM `horse`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `file` ON (`file`.`fk_id`=`horse`.`id`
                           AND `file`.`fk_object`="horse_photo")
GROUP BY `horse`.`id`
ORDER BY `horse`.`id` ASC,
         `file`.`is_default` DESC,
         `file`.`position` ASC;
```

To be clear, I want to retrieve all horses and their default photo (if there is one).

**More Details:**
File.is_default is a boolean with either 0 or 1. File.position is UNSIGNED INT starting at 0. The file joined should first be is_default=1, and then resolve to File.position=0 (or the smallest int).

The results I'm getting:
A list sorted by horse.id ASC, however the File joined appears to just be the first File (ordered by the primary id column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in the comment to my first answer, no, you cannot order anything used in a join. You can't order a view, inline function, derived table, CTE, or a subquery without using restrictive commands.

So, let me give this one more try. You want a query that returns one record per horse. If there is a default photo, return that photo. If there is no default, return the one with the lowest position number. Now, I'm a big fan of CTEs, as you'll see below. If you're new to CTEs, this may be confusing, but they can make your life a lot easier once you master them!

The first CTE (i.e., Default_Photo) will bring back, for each horse, the data on any default photo that exists. If there is no default photo, then there will be no record for that horse.

The second CTE (i.e., Next_Best_Photos) will bring back one row for each horse with the minimum position number for photos that are not the default. This will contain non-default photos even for horses that do have default photos. That's the way it's supposed to be.

The third CTE (i.e., Final_Dataset) will bring back one distinct row for each horse. If that horse is missing a corresponding row in the Default_Photos CTE (i.e., it does not have a default photo), then it will display the information associated with the photo with the minimum position.

The reason you need the third query is because, in t-sql (which is what I use), when you use the distinct command, it will not let you sort by derived columns.

```
With Default_Photos as (
Select H.ID
    , F.ID as 'FID'
    , F.Position

From Horse H
    Inner Join File F
        on H.ID = F.ID

Where F.is_default = 1
)

, Next_Best_Photo as (
Select H.ID
    , F.ID as 'FID'
    , Min(F.Position) as Min_Position

From Horse H
    Inner Join File F
        on H.ID = F.ID

Where F.is_default = 0

Group by H.ID
    , F.ID
)

, Final_Dataset as (
Select Distinct H.ID
    , H.name
    , F.ID as 'FID'
    , Case
        When DP.ID is null
            Then 1
            Else 0
        End as is_default
    , Case
        When DP.ID is null
            Then F2.Position
            Else DP.Position
        End as position

From Horse H
    Inner Join File F
        on H.ID = F.ID
    Left Outer Join Default_Photos DP
        on H.ID = DP.ID
    Left Outer Join Next_Best_Photo NBP
        on H.ID = NBP.ID
    Left Outer Join File F2
        on NBP.FID = F2.ID
            and NBP.Min_Position = F2.Position
)

Select *

From Final_Dataset

Order by id asc
    , is_default desc
    , position asc
```

There may be an easier way to do this, but this is how I construct datasets for my dashboards where I need to be absolutely sure I only get one row per ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are grouping by horse id but not using any aggregate functions on the other columns you are selecting, if you group on one column every other column you select has to be a sum, or max, or min, etc. This should work:

```
SELECT `horse`.`id`, `horse`.`name`, `file`.`id` AS `fid`, `file`.`is_default`, `file`.`position`
FROM `horse`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `file` ON (`file`.`fk_id`=`horse`.`id` AND `file`.`fk_object`="horse_photo")
GROUP BY `horse`.`id`, `horse`.`name`, `file`.`id` AS `fid`, `file`.`is_default`, `file`.`position`
ORDER BY `horse`.`id` ASC, `file`.`is_default` DESC, `file`.`position` ASC;
```

Comment: That gave me a syntax error because of the GROUP BY `file`.`id` AS `fid`... if I change it to just `file`.`id` or `fid` it executes. However, that gives me a row for every file. Is that the intended result?

Comment: I was going to say that query is dependent on the data having a 1 to 1 relationship, if there can be more than one file for each horse you will have to edit the join to only return one file.

Comment: Ignore that last comment from me. I would have assumed it is, but if you do not want to get the horse picture for each horse you will have to explain a little more precisely  exactly what result you are trying to get.

Comment: Well the query I posted is over simplified, but basically i'm wanting one record for each horse with the filepath for that horse's default photo. So my result set would be horse.id, horse.name, file.id, file.filename. Each horse has many files designated by file.fk_object and file.fk_id. Fk_object could be for instance, horse_photo, horse_pedigree, etc... and Fk_id is the foreign key for horse.id.

Comment: But there should be only one fk_object`="horse_photo" for each horse?

Comment: No, each horse has several photos, several pedigrees with their file information all stored in the file table. (Not the actual files just their path info).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question and your current results, then the problem is that you are not specifying that File.is_Default=1. That, paired with the fact that you're grouping by Horse.id, is giving you one row per horse with whichever photo it finds first.

If you add "file.is_default=1" to your join criteria or a new Where clause then you should get the results you want. If you put the "file.is_default=1" in the join criteria and there is no default photo, any file columns will return a null value for that horse. If you put "file.is_default=1" in the Where clause, a horse with no default photo will not appear in the result set.

Also, to make it easier for people to read your code, I would recommend aliasing your tables and maybe indenting your code rather than having everything for each clause on a single line.

Comment: Well... I want it to return a photo if it has one... Let's forget is_default for a minute and say I wanted to return the first file sorted alphabetically by filename. Is it not possible to just order a join arbitrarily? P.S I formatted the SQL above now.